# CFRelease but still leaking

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio

this takes my head in. I read audio from the iPod Library for analysis of the audio samples and I can do what I want, the buffer is always leaking, I get a Low Memory Warning and the app is killed.
I tried all suggestions but to no success. The code below is incorporated in a static library and reading the audio works fine, just the buffer gets never released. I use `ARC` and also tried NOT to call `CFRelease` but same thing ... thanks for any suggestion, I am completely stuck!!!

```
- (NSInteger) getMP3Samples:(SInt16*)address{
    AudioBufferList audioBufferList;

    if (_assetReader == nil) {
        return 0;
    }

    _mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount = 0;
    CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer =[_assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];

    // Is the Song ended
    if (nextBuffer == nil){
        if ([_assetReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusCompleted) {
            [_assetReader cancelReading];
        }
        _assetReader = nil;
        _assetReaderOutput = nil;
        return _mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount;
    }

    CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
        nextBuffer,
        NULL,
        &audioBufferList,
        sizeof(audioBufferList),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
        &_mp3Control.blockBuffer);

    if (nextBuffer) {
        CMSampleBufferInvalidate(nextBuffer);
        CFRelease(nextBuffer);
        nextBuffer=NULL;
    }

    for (int b=0; b < audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers; b++) {
        memcpy((void *)(address+_mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount),(void *)audioBufferList.mBuffers[b].mData,audioBufferList.mBuffers[b].mDataByteSize);
        _mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount+=audioBufferList.mBuffers[b].mDataByteSize;
    }
    ///
    /// Return samples and not bytes!!
    ///
    return _mp3Control.currentSampleBufferCount/2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using & releasing the block buffer returned by `CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer` in the (not posted) calling code?
If you are not releasing the object stored in `&_mp3Control.blockBuffer` after calling `getMP3Samples:`, this could be your memory management problem. (Core Foundation-style objects don't participate in ARC)

You could also run your code through the Allocation & Leaks Instruments to see further details (I am just guessing here :) ).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the reason! And I even can do it inside the function itself since I memcpy the samples into another buffer. Thanks a lot again, I must say Apples documentation is very thin here ...

Comment: You are welcome! 
Yes - Documentation is a bit thin occasionally. But you can always try the headers (e.g. by cmd+clicking the method name in Xcode). In case of Core Media the headers currently contain way more text than the actual docs :)